# Real time audio processing with python and AudioSegment

Tags: python, pyaudio, pydub, pyav

Well for some reason i want to split some selected mp3 files to chunk-time: ~28msec.

I have quality problem for slicing<1sec.

```
from av import AudioFrame
from pydub import AudioSegment
import av

#open an mp3 file
sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(r"ΑΓΙΑ ΣΚΕΠΗ.mp3")

codec = av.CodecContext.create('pcm_s16le', 'r')
codec.sample_rate = 44100
codec.channels = 2

#split the file each part 10 second
#slices = sound1[::10000]

#split the file each part 2 second
#slices = sound1[::2000]

#split the file each part 1 second
#slices = sound1[::1000] #ok quality 1 tick every 1 second

#split the file each part 10 millisecond
slices = sound1[::10] #bad quality

pieces = AudioSegment.silent()


'''
for slice in slices:
    pieces = pieces+slice
    
pieces.export("remaked.mp3",format="mp3")
#remaked works well
'''


for slice in slices:
    
    #qualty loss (why?)
    packet = av.Packet(slice.raw_data)
    frame = codec.decode(packet)[0]
    
    #remake AudioSegment from Av.AudioFrame
    for p in frame.planes:
        data = p.to_bytes()
        data_segment = AudioSegment(data, sample_width=2, channels=2, frame_rate=44100)
        pieces = pieces+data_segment
        
pieces.export("remaked.mp3",format="mp3")
```

How can i fix the quality problem?

Note that i use av.AudioFrame (`frame = codec.decode(packet)[0]`) because i want to send some real time audio data with aiortc

**Edit:**

```
from av import AudioFrame
from pydub import AudioSegment
import pyaudio
import av
import fractions

from aiortc.mediastreams import MediaStreamTrack

class RadioTelephoneTrack(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "audio"
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # don't forget this!
        
        self.sample_rate = 8000
        self.AUDIO_PTIME = 0.020  # 20ms audio packetization
        self.samples = int(self.AUDIO_PTIME * self.sample_rate)

        self.FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.CHANNELS = 2
        self.RATE = self.sample_rate
        #self.RATE = 44100
        self.CHUNK = int(8000*0.020)
        #self.CHUNK = 1024
        
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.mic_stream = self.p.open(format=self.FORMAT, channels=1,rate=self.RATE, input=True,frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)
        
        self.codec = av.CodecContext.create('pcm_s16le', 'r')
        self.codec.sample_rate = self.RATE
        #self.codec.sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16
        self.codec.channels = 2
        #self.codec.channel_layout = "mono";
        
        self.sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file(r"ΑΓΙΑ ΣΚΕΠΗ.mp3").set_frame_rate(self.sample_rate)
        print("Frame rate: "+str(self.sound1.frame_rate))
        #self.sound1_channels = self.sound1.split_to_mono()
        #self.sound1 = self.sound1_channels[0].overlay(self.sound1_channels[1])
        self.audio_samples = 0
        self.chunk_number = 0
        #self.sound1 = self.sound1 - 30 # make sound1 quiter 30dB
        
    async def recv(self):
        mic_data = self.mic_stream.read(self.CHUNK)
        mic_sound = AudioSegment(mic_data, sample_width=2, channels=1, frame_rate=self.RATE)
        mic_sound = AudioSegment.from_mono_audiosegments(mic_sound, mic_sound)
        mic_sound_duration = len(mic_sound)
        #print("Mic sound duration: "+str(mic_sound_duration))
        
        mp3_slice_duration = mic_sound_duration
        
        if(len(self.sound1)>(self.chunk_number+1)*mp3_slice_duration):
            sound1_part = self.sound1[self.chunk_number*mp3_slice_duration:(self.chunk_number+1)*mp3_slice_duration]
        elif(len(self.sound1)>(self.chunk_number)*mp3_slice_duration):
            sound1_part = self.sound1[self.chunk_number*mp3_slice_duration:]
        else:
            #replay
            
            times_played_1 = int((self.chunk_number)*mp3_slice_duration/len(self.sound1))
            times_played_2 = int((self.chunk_number+1)*mp3_slice_duration/len(self.sound1))
            if(times_played_1==times_played_2):
                time_start = ((self.chunk_number)*mp3_slice_duration)-(times_played_1*len(self.sound1))
                time_end = ((self.chunk_number+1)*mp3_slice_duration)-(times_played_1*len(self.sound1))
                sound1_part = self.sound1[time_start:time_end]
            else:
                time_start_1 = ((self.chunk_number)*mp3_slice_duration)-(times_played_1*len(self.sound1))
                sound1_part1 = self.sound1[time_start_1:]
                
                time_end_1 = ((self.chunk_number+1)*mp3_slice_duration)-(times_played_2*len(self.sound1))
                sound1_part2 = self.sound1[0:time_end_1]
                
                sound1_part = sound1_part1.append(sound1_part2, crossfade=5)
            
            #sound1_part = AudioSegment.silent()
            
        #self.mix_sound = sound1_part.overlay(mic_sound)
        
        
        self.mix_sound = sound1_part
        
        packet = av.Packet(self.mix_sound.raw_data)
        frame = self.codec.decode(packet)[0]
        
        frame.pts = self.audio_samples
        self.audio_samples += frame.samples
        
        
        self.chunk_number = self.chunk_number+1
        return frame
```

The above code works (pretty better).
The main problems now are:

1. The sound sounds in depth.
2. There is click noise every time the sound re-starts (starts from the beginning).

Comment: Are you processing the slices in between splitting and rejoining?  If so, then unless you take steps to merge the endpoints, it's natural you would get a discontinuity between slices.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim, I just want to make a real time MediaStreamTrack like this: https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/71cd9334405886e5974441e192a816d54a5b16e5/src/aiortc/mediastreams.py#L30

Comment: One remaked.mp3 @slice-time=30msec https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CoTs8FooIYe2s5KUaHUFQnVrQIDW8-HH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  What are you DOING to the slices between split and rejoin?  If you aren't changing the bits, then there should be no interruptions.  You show a `codec`, but you aren't doing anything with the codec.  Are you changing the sample rate?

Comment: No, aiortc MediaTrack needs pyAv AudioFrames.
I want to mix mp3 files, microphone input, manage sound strength, sound speed,..., and when the AudioFrame is ready then send the sound to browser client.

Comment: If you're doing mixing and such, you can't process them in small chunks.  You have to do your processing as a continuous stream, and then chop into buffers at the very last minute.  Otherwise, you can't know that the slope of the last sample of chunk N-1 actually matches the slope of the first sample of chunk N.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good news! Check the edit.

Comment: I don't know what "sounds in depth" means.  There is always a click when restarting a clip.  The way to avoid that is to fade out and fade in: multiply the last few samples by decreasing factors to 0, and the first few samples by increasing factors from 0 to 1.

Comment: Suggested time window (total) for fade effecf? in depth: sounds like the sound source is far away.

Comment: Not very long. A few cycles -- less than 10.